# In need of interpretation of a ordered-subset related problem.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

''Given a set $S_n = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$, we define a *preference list* to be an ordered subset of $S_n$. Let $P_n$ be the number of preference lists of $S_n$. Show that for positive integers $n > m$, $P_n - P_m$ is divisible by $n - m$.

*Note: the empty set and $S_n$ are subsets of $S_n$.*''

Can anyone help me out to make me understand the problem ? **(giving an explained example of this question will be very good )** 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For example, for $n=3$ the preference lists of $\{1,2,3\}$ are
$$ \emptyset\\
(1)\\
(2)\\
(3)\\
(1, 2)\\
(2, 1)\\
(1, 3)\\
(3, 1)\\
(2, 3)\\
(3, 2)\\
(1, 2, 3)\\
(1, 3, 2)\\
(2, 1, 3)\\
(2, 3, 1)\\
(3, 1, 2)\\
(3, 2, 1)$$